# Uncaught error: Signalr jquery error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I am getting error while implementing Signalr in asp.net C# like:

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.
```

I am implementing signalr in visual studio 2010 and I have implemented same code before but that is working fine. Please help me to resolve this error.
My code is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="SignalRTest._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {

             var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

             IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                 $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
             };

             $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
                 IWannaChat.server.send($('#txtMessage').val());
             });

             $.connection.hub.start();
         });
    </script>




  <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtMessage" />
        <input type="button" id="SendMessage" value="broadcast" />
        <ul id="listMessages">
        </ul>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my code behind is like this:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports System.Net

Namespace SignalRChat
    <HubName("myChatHub")> _
    Public Class LetsChat
        Inherits Hub
        Public Sub send(message As String)
            message = "User : " + Dns.GetHostName() + " User :" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + " Message : " + message


            Clients.Caller.addMessage(message)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

my global.asax is like this:

```
   Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this, to set the hook on the button once connection started:

```
 $(function () {
    var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

    IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
         $("#SendMessage").click(function () {
             IWannaChat.server.send($('#txtMessage').val());
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: not working please provide complete javascrilpt code if possible

Comment: nothing is happening on button click after replacing my code with this code.please help

Comment: @Androidlearner add `<script>` tag on bottom of the page before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Actually sendMessage in not getting called. I checked with debugger.

Comment: I am not getting anything niether error nor any msg.

Comment: @Androidlearner you have to debug the javascript. Put 'debugger;' in the code, for example in the anonymous function inside 'done'.